# grab json value within datatable button

Tags: jquery, datatables

Trying to figure out how I can grab the json value and access it when clicking on the datatable button.

Here is the datatable:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'api/getLaneData.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        $('#loadingDiv').hide();
        $('.box-body').show();
        let jsonObject = JSON.parse(data);    
        let table = $('#example2').DataTable({  
         "data": jsonObject,
           "columns": [  
              { "data": "COLUMN1" },
              { "data": "COLUMN2" },
              // and so on
            ],
          "iDisplayLength": 50,
          "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
          "paging": true,
          "scrollY": 300,
          "scrollX": true,
          "bDestroy": true,
          "stateSave": true,
          "sPaginationType":"full_numbers",
          "autoWidth": true,
          "deferRender": true,
          "dom": 'Bfrtip',
          "buttons": [
            {
              text: '<i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Lane',
              className: 'addLane btn btn-primary btn-sm',
              action: function (e, dt, node, config){
                // HERE IS WHERE I AM TRYING TO ACCESS THE DATA
                console.log('this is data' + data.COLUMN1);
              }
            }
          ]
       });
     },
     error: function(jqHHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
     }
  });
```

Doing the above, I am getting an undefined error.

How can I access the data within the button?

Comment: I suspect that the scope of your data: `data` variable is not global.  To confirm, you can change your console.log to `console.log(typeof data);` and if it returns 'undefined' then this is the case. You could also just try binding the data to your function, eg: `function (e, dt, node, config){ var data = this; .. }.bind(data)`

Comment: @Drew - using console.log(typeof data), the output is "string"

Comment: well it's not undefined but its also not an 'object' which is what your expecting it to be since you are trying to access property values of the data object, eg: `data.COLUMN1`.  Assuming the bind suggestion doesn't work, then the next step would be to determine where the data object your passing into your ajax request is overwritten with/changedto a string

Comment: I think the "data" you are trying to access in your button is the ajax response data, which you store in the 'jsonObject' variable, eg: `let jsonObject = JSON.parse(data);`.  You probably want `jsonObject.COLUMN1` ?  However, you will still need to bind that jsonObject to your butons function since that variable will go out of scope at the end of the ajax success function call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you forgot to add **dom: 'Bfrtip',** to your dt and your data variable is an array of objects.

Because your question is:

> How can I access the data within the button?

You can access the data within the button as a datatable attribute:

> [this.data()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/data()): This method provides access to the raw data that is
> used for each row in the tables in the API's context.

A demo:

```js
var data = {
    "data": [
        [
            "Shou Itou",
            "Regional Marketing",
            "Tokyo",
            "8899",
            "2011\/08\/14",
            "$163,000"
        ],
        [
            "Michelle House",
            "Integration Specialist",
            "Sydney",
            "2769",
            "2011\/06\/02",
            "$95,400"
        ],
        [
            "Suki Burks",
            "Developer",
            "London",
            "6832",
            "2009\/10\/22",
            "$114,500"
        ],
        [
            "Prescott Bartlett",
            "Technical Author",
            "London",
            "3606",
            "2011\/05\/07",
            "$145,000"
        ],
        [
            "Gavin Cortez",
            "Team Leader",
            "San Francisco",
            "2860",
            "2008\/10\/26",
            "$235,500"
        ],
        [
            "Martena Mccray",
            "Post-Sales support",
            "Edinburgh",
            "8240",
            "2011\/03\/09",
            "$324,050"
        ],
        [
            "Unity Butler",
            "Marketing Designer",
            "San Francisco",
            "5384",
            "2009\/12\/09",
            "$85,675"
        ],
        [
            "Howard Hatfield",
            "Office Manager",
            "San Francisco",
            "7031",
            "2008\/12\/16",
            "$164,500"
        ],
        [
            "Cara Stevens",
            "Sales Assistant",
            "New York",
            "3990",
            "2011\/12\/06",
            "$145,600"
        ],
        [
            "Hermione Butler",
            "Regional Director",
            "London",
            "1016",
            "2011\/03\/21",
            "$356,250"
        ],
        [
            "Lael Greer",
            "Systems Administrator",
            "London",
            "6733",
            "2009\/02\/27",
            "$103,500"
        ],
        [
            "Jonas Alexander",
            "Developer",
            "San Francisco",
            "8196",
            "2010\/07\/14",
            "$86,500"
        ],
        [
            "Shad Decker",
            "Regional Director",
            "Edinburgh",
            "6373",
            "2008\/11\/13",
            "$183,000"
        ],
        [
            "Michael Bruce",
            "Javascript Developer",
            "Singapore",
            "5384",
            "2011\/06\/27",
            "$183,000"
        ],
        [
            "Donna Snider",
            "Customer Support",
            "New York",
            "4226",
            "2011\/01\/25",
            "$112,000"
        ]
    ]
};

/*
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:63342/StackOverflow/1.json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {},
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    */
        $('#loadingDiv').hide();
        $('.box-body').show();
        let jsonObject = data.data; // JSON.parse(data).data;
        let table = $('#example2').DataTable({
            "data": jsonObject,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            "buttons": [
                {
                    text: '<i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Lane',
                    className: 'addLane btn btn-primary btn-sm',
                    action: function (e, dt, node, config){
                        // HERE IS WHERE I AM TRYING TO ACCESS THE DATA
                        console.log(data.data[0]);
                        console.log('this is data' + JSON.stringify(data));
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
        /*
    },
    error: function(jqHHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    }
});
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.4/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>


<div id="loadingDiv">loadingDiv</div>
<div class="box-body">
    <table id="example2" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Extn.</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Extn.</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I updated my question to include some more datatable features, including dom: Bfrtip

Comment: with **this.data()** I get the array of   array. Let me know

Comment: So I did this:  console.log(this.data) and I got this: ƒ (){var d=b.apply(a,arguments);r.extend(d,d,c.methodExt);return d}

Comment: @JohnBeasley Beacause it is a function you should call it: **console.log(this.data())**  Rember to add the **()**

Comment: I did indeed forget to add the ().  Upon making the correction, I was able to access the data.  Thank you, sir.